# android pdf viewer sdk for embed hyperlink support

Tags: android, pdf

I am intending to develop an android app which support pdf reading functionality with hyper link support.Means I want to show embeded hyperlink in pdf and user click on that hyperlink my app need to redirect to browser.
I don't want to use google docs.I have found some open source pdf sdk but I am not able to provide support for hyperlink.Please suggest me if any open source sdk available which also provide hyperlink support.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through WebView or by downloading PDF and opening Intent of installed app. But, I am using a third party API, it is unable to open hyperlinked PDF. The two ways that I described above can be achieved through

```
if (!canDisplayPdf()) {
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WebActivity.class);
i.putExtra("url", alist.get(position).toString());
//alist.get(position).toString() is hyperlinked pdf url
startActivity(i);
}
else
{
try
{
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Opening PDF... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Intent inte = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(alist.get(position).toString()));
//inte.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(alist.get(position).toString()), "application/pdf");
startActivity(inte);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
Log.e("Activity Not Found", e.getMessage());
}

// If canDisplayPDF function() will ensure whether device has PDF application or not.

public boolean canDisplayPdf() {
PackageManager packageManager = getApplication().getPackageManager();
Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
if (packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0) {
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
```